# Multi-stage build - switching image from python to ubuntu

Tags: python, docker, pip, docker-multi-stage-build

I am doing multi-stage build currently with:

```
FROM python:3.9.6-slim AS base
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y build-essential
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --prefix=/install --no-warn-script-location

FROM python:3.9.6-slim
COPY --from=base /install /usr/local
...
```

Now I wanted to switch to ubuntu:20.04 image, however there is a difference:

- With python image modules get installed to `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` and `sys.path` contains `/usr/local/lib/python3.9`
- With ubuntu image modules get installed to `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, but `sys.path` contains `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` and Python is not able to find the modules

Now I read a bit about site-packages vs dist-packages, but I'm still confused. Maybe I could do a simple `mv`, but it seems a bit hacky... So how to make it work in a clean way?

Comment: There's actually both `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` and `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` in `sys.path`. Still it's dist- not site-... So where would be the correct dir to copy the stuff into?

Comment: Oh, I was wrong about /usr/local, sorry about that. Have you tried not copying random stuff anywhere, but installing it with `pip install -e .`?

Comment: I read `-e` is for editable/development mode, I don't see how exactly I should use it and how it can help here...?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you're doing with the two-stage build. Sorry for the noise.